# swift: Use of undeclared type 'FMDatabase'

Tags: swift, sqlite

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift) to get SQLite working on my project, but I can't get past [section 3.1.1](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift#Step3_1_1). Here's my code so far:

```
import Foundation

let sharedInstance = ModelManager()

class ModelManager: NSObject {
    var database: FMDatabase? = nil
    class func getInstance() -> ModelManager
    {
        if(sharedInstance.database == nil) {
            sharedInstance.database = FMDatabase(path: Utility.getPath("Student.sqlite"))
        }
        return sharedInstance
    }
}
```

I get an error `Use of undeclared type 'FMDatabase'`

Now, I followed the tutorial mostly, with minor differences since I'm not starting from scratch.

1. **Entire Section 1:** I didn't need to create a layout, so I didn't.
2. **Section 2.1:** I put the FMDB files, FMDatabase, FMDatabaseAdditions, and FMDResultSet in directory ThirdParty/FMDB/. Copied them over from another project that had that.
3. **Section 2.2:** There was no `libsqlite3.0.dylib` in the link library. Only `libsqlite3.0.tbd`
4. **Section 2.4:** I didn't add a bridging header, as one was already present. So I added `#import "FMDatabase.h"` to the existing one.

Here's the code:

```
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#ifndef SmartLife_Bridging_Header_h
#define SmartLife_Bridging_Header_h
#import "Pods/FormatterKit/FormatterKit/TTTTimeIntervalFormatter.h"
#endif
```

I also think the existing `Bridging-Header.h` is setup correctly.

[image]

(Note: The `Yes` in `Install Objective-C Compatibility Header` is not shown by default, unless the row is clicked)

**EDIT:** Here's some of my project directory, the ones showing the FMDB files, and the Bridging-Header.h:

[image]

Is there anything I missed? Anything I can try?

Comment: could you add a screenshot showing your project files (i.e. along the left side of the Xcode IDE window)?  I'm interested in seeing if Xcode knows where the ThirdParty folder and files are (i.e. are they red in the file inspector or are they black?)

Comment: is there a "`FMDB.h`" file available that you can add to your bridging header file?  that is.. instead of importing `FMDatabase.h`, can you import `FMDB.h`" if it exists?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, nope, there isn't any, sorry. The tutorial I linked to didn't call for one, either.

Comment: Did you try a Swift SQLite library? http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift is very similar to FMDB, but it feels more Swifty, and you'll avoid bridging issues.